# Remove hover property for an element after it is declared in stylesheet

Tags: javascript, css, hover

Is it possible to remove or cancel  `:hover` effects once it is declared in a stylesheet?

For example..

I have a class with a `:hover` effect in the stylesheet. For one element in this class (and there are many), I'd want to not have these hover effects.

So rather than go thru each class where I'd want to do this, is there a way to simply cancel a `:hover` effect? I'm thinking this may need some javascript.

update with a brief example:

```
.class1 {a bunch of properties that vary based on the class}
.class1:hover {a bunch of properties that vary based on the class}
.class2 {a bunch of properties that vary based on the class}
.class2:hover {a bunch of properties that vary based on the class}
```

For one element in one of these classes, I'd like it to not participate in the hovering festivities, but still want it to be in the class. I do not want to have to create new classes for just the hovering. Is this possible?

Comment: Have you tried to do a CSS Reset?  Also how would you not know what is declared?  You could look at the source to see the style sheet and what it is doing.

Comment: Then wouldn't I need to list the properties I'd want to reset?

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your question. Can you please provide an example (CSS+HTML) of the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Can you add you code and give some examples? I can think of a few solutions, just need to know which apply :)

Comment: Could you provide your real code? perhaps through http://jsfiddle.net ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I gather...it's not possible :(

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing your actual code or attributes that change on hover, one way to solve this would be to change the attribute back, for example:

http://jsfiddle.net/MfqDg/

```
<div class="class1"></div>
<div class="class1"></div>
<div class="class1"></div>​

.class1{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid;
    margin: 20px;
}

.class1:hover{
    background: #000;
}

.class1:nth-child(2):hover{
    background: none;
}
​
```

Comment: Thanks, I've never come across that technique...however, this would be just as useful as an inline style, something I don't want to do. I'll try to get more code up like you asked :)

Comment: So then what exactly are you looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Just be more specific with your targeting. Say you have lots of things with a class "foo" - rather than using `.foo:hover {color:red}`, and then `p .foo:hover {color:black}`, `table .foo:hover {color:black}`, just say `.container p .foo:hover {color:red}`, then the other instances won't have the style applied. Does that make sense?

Comment: I suppose...I was looking for more of a specific way of removing the stylesheet's doings.

Comment: Not that I know of - the only way you can do this is to set the attribute back to the initial value. It's better practice to have more specific rules to start with, than to try and hack something to undo your general rules.